# Grid View adjustment in different divs

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have a Asp.net gridview which is assigned a data source. the grid view is residing inside a div with fix height. I want to create another div if rows exceed 20.So that only first 20 rows are shown on first div and for other 20 rows a new dynamic div is to created and remaining rows are to be placed inside it. any suggestions

Comment: Consider sending the additional content in an ajax response which can be directly injected into the HTML page or use grid view's paging functionality.

Answer (score 0):

In first GridView lets call it "GridViewA" disable paging and set `PageSize` to 20.

If your DataSource exceeds 20 records put another GridView called "GridViewB" into your other div, disable paging, set PageSize to 20, set the same DataSource as "GridViewA" have. The only difference is you need to set current page to 2.

Using this approach you will show 1-20 records in "GridViewA" and 21-n in "GridViewB".

Comment: i have tried this approcah but if i have 55 rows then all are added in GridViewA even if PageSize is set to 20

Comment: Yes, all the rows will always be in GridViewA, thats why you just need to limit user to see only first page with first 20 records.